# How do I create an event handler for a programmatically created object in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say I have an object that I dynamically create. For example, say I create a button called "MyButton":

```
Dim MyButton as New Button()
MyButton.Name = "MyButton"
```

How do I create, say, a "Click" event? If it were statically created I could create a function as:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(ByVal sender as system.object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles.
```

How do I implement an event handler for MyButton?

Answer (score 38):

You use `AddHandler` and `AddressOf` like this:

```
Dim MyButton as New Button()
MyButton.Name = "MyButton"
AddHandler MyButton.Click, AddressOf MyButton_Click
```

There is more info here in the MSDN documentation:

- [How to: Add an Event Handler Using Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

With the newer versions of VB.NET you can use a lambda expression inline instead of an entire method (if you want)

```
Dim MyButton as New Button()
MyButton.Name = "MyButton"
AddHandler MyButton.Click, Sub(sender2, eventargs2)
                               'code to do stuff
                               'more code to do stuff
                           End Sub
```