# Dynamic button click event handler

Tags: vb.net

I've 100 buttons created dynamically in a form. How can I an add event handler to them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I create an event handler for a programmatically created object in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net)*.

Answer (score 59):

You can use [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to add a handler for any event.

For example, this might be:

```
AddHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.theButton_Click
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `RemoveHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click` if you dispose of buttons programatically.

Comment: It might be more clear if you use `AddHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.theButton_Click` as that would follow the default naming convention.  Or you could call it `Me.HandlerOf_thButton_Click`.

Answer (score 17):

Just to round out Reed's answer, you can either get the `Button` objects from the `Form` or other container and add the handler, or you could create the `Button` objects programmatically.
If you get the `Button` objects from the `Form` or other container, then you can iterate over the `Controls` collection of the `Form` or other container control, such as `Panel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` and so on. You can then just add the click handler with
`AddHandler ctrl.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click` (variables as in the code below),
but I prefer to check the type of the `Control` and cast to a `Button` so as I'm not adding click handlers for any other controls in the container (such as Labels). Remember that you can add handlers for any event of the `Button` at this point using `AddHandler`.
Alternatively, you can create the `Button` objects programmatically, as in the second block of code below.
Then, of course, you have to write the handler method, as in the third code block below.

Here is an example using `Form` as the container, but you're probably better off using a `Panel` or some other container control.

```
Dim btn as Button = Nothing
For Each ctrl As Control in myForm.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click   ' From answer by Reed.
    End If
 Next
```

Alternatively creating the `Button`s  programmatically, this time adding to a `Panel` container.

```
Dim Panel1 As new Panel()
For i As Integer = 1 to 100
    btn = New Button()
    ' Set Button properties or call a method to do so.
    Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)  ' Add Button to the container.
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click   ' Again from the answer by Reed.
Next
```

Then your handler will look something like this

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Button clicks here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

@Debasish Sahu, your answer is an answer to another question, namely: how to know which button (or any other control) was clicked when there is a common handler for a couple of controls? So I'm giving an answer to this question how I usually do it, almost the same as yours, but note that also works without type conversion when it handles the same type of Controls:

```
Private Sub btn_done_clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim selectedBtn As Button = sender
    MsgBox("you have clicked button " & selectedBtn.Name)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed a common event handler in which I can show from which button it is called without  using switch case... and done like this..

```
  Private Sub btn_done_clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    MsgBox.Show("you have clicked button " & CType(CType(sender,  _
    System.Windows.Forms.Button).Tag, String))

  End Sub
```

Comment: Then you also need to assign `Tag` to every button. You could have just got a `Name` instead. The benefit is that `Name` uniquely identifies a control, whereas `Tag` values can be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Some code for a variation on this problem. Using the above code got me my click events as needed, but I was then stuck trying to work out which button had been clicked.
My scenario is I have a dynamic amount of tab pages. On each tab page are (all dynamically created) 2 charts, 2 DGVs and a pair of radio buttons. Each control has a unique name relative to the tab, but there could be 20 radio buttons with the same name if I had 20 tab pages. The radio buttons switch between which of the 2 graphs and DGVs you get to see. Here is the code for when one of the radio buttons gets checked (There's a nearly identical block that swaps the charts and DGVs back):

```
   Private Sub radioFit_Components_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If sender.name = "radioFit_Components" And sender.visible Then
        If sender.checked Then
            For Each ctrl As Control In TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls
                Select Case ctrl.Name
                    Case "embChartSSE_Components"
                        ctrl.BringToFront()
                    Case "embChartSSE_Fit_Curve"
                        ctrl.SendToBack()
                    Case "dgvFit_Components"
                        ctrl.BringToFront()
                End Select
            Next

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This code will fire for any of the tab pages and swap the charts and DGVs over on any of the tab pages. The sender.visible check is to stop the code firing when the form is being created.