# How to make a click event for runtime created controls in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I added some controls to my form at runtime and I need them to call a function when clicked. I don't know how many controls will be added but they all need to run the same function. How would I define the event? Can I define events based on all controls of a given class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple example :

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' creating control
        Dim btn1 As Button = New Button()
        Dim btn2 As Button = New Button()

        btn1.Parent = Me
        btn1.Name = "btn1"
        btn1.Top = 10
        btn1.Text = "Btn1"

        btn2.Parent = Me
        btn2.Name = "btn2"
        btn2.Top = 50
        btn2.Text = "Btn2"

        'adding handler for click event
        AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick
        AddHandler btn2.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick


    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDynamicButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

        If btn.Name = "btn1" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Btn1 clicked")
        ElseIf btn.Name = "btn2" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Btn2 Clicked")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why the `if..then..elseif...elseif...elseif...` construct? Just give `AddHandler` the `AddressOf` the appropriate event handler method in the first place, no?

Comment: `if else ` construct is used to decide on which of the dynamic control click action was done!

Comment: I know that. Just saying it's not needed: if for each button you have a different implementation of a `Click` event handler, just register a different handler for each button.

Comment: Almost every single control I display on a form whatsoever, is a dynamic one. I lost count when I stopped drag-and-dropping buttons.

Comment: yes ofcs they are, but am talking about that are not created in visual using the Designer!

Comment: FYI, I've upvoted this because it shows the AddHandler line I was looking for, but I agree with Mat's Mug that it is better coding style to create different handler methods where different action is desired, rather than to create a single handler method which tests (If) to distinguish the buttons.  IMHO, its even cleaner to create separate handlers when two buttons have very similar action. Each handler can call a common method, passing in parameter(s) to get the desired differences in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
AddHandler Control.Event, AddressOf MethodExecuting
```

For example:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf ClickMethod
```