# How to programmatically add a button to my windows form, which will open a macro on click?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a macro file. I want to add a button in a windows form of my application, on click of which this macro file will open, so that the user can run the macro by themselves. Has anybody come across similar coding scenario who can guide with some code? I am using vb.net.

Comment: Are you looking for [Run batch file in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net) and [How to make a click event for runtime created controls in Visual Basic 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948332/how-to-make-a-click-event-for-runtime-created-controls-in-visual-basic-2010)

Comment: hello Andrew, to give some details, I have added a  'customized addin' tab in microsoft powerpoint ribbon. When User opens certain drawings from my .net application, the drawings open in powerpoint with the added new tab beside Home,Insert,Design,Transition etc.. Now i want to add a button in my tab which will open a micro. If user runs this macro, the drawing calculations will get auto checked. I am stuck with the part how I can open the macro on the button click.

Comment: what macro do u mean? batch?

Comment: its a .pptm file. the code written inside this file is in vba. But my complete application is written in vb. I just want to execute this vba script ona button click from my application form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button1_Click
Process.Start(Macro Location)
```

If you can compile the macro, you can run it as an exe, so you don't have to boot the IDE to run it.