# How to run the same sub for every single button on a form?

Tags: vb.net

I have 81 buttons on a form (9x9 grid), each is named "X_Y" (such as "5_2" for X=5,Y=2). I want each button to run the same sub. There are no other buttons on the same form.

I could just do this: `Private Sub TileClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 0_0.Click, 0_1.Click, 0_2.Click,` and so on (up to 8_8.Click), but if there's an easier/simpler way, then I'd rather do that.

Either some way to handle any button click, or something like a For loop to go through all 81 buttons.

Comment: What do you want the buttons to do? Could what you to do be done in a method and then call that method for each button?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea that you don't manually put all of those buttons on the form at design-time. Programmatically adding the buttons at run-time would be a better choice - and you can then add the handler at the time that you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim btn as Button = Nothing
For Each ctrl As Control in myForm.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
    End If
Next
```

[Refer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)