# Creating multiple click events for dynamic buttons in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When creating a button I want to create a click event for each button. How do I create a click event for each button created dynamically? Here is my code.  It works to create a single event based on the first button created.

```
    Sub CreateDynamicButton()
    Dim ButtonNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim axisX As Integer = 53
    Dim axisY As Integer = 13
    ' Create a Button object 
    Do Until ButtonNumber = 11
        Dim dynamicButton As New Button
        ' Set Button properties
        dynamicButton.Location = New Point(axisX, axisY)
        dynamicButton.Height = 30
        dynamicButton.Width = 200
        ' Set background and foreground
        dynamicButton.BackColor = Color.Beige
        dynamicButton.ForeColor = Color.Black
        dynamicButton.Text = "I am Dynamic Button" & ButtonNumber
        dynamicButton.Name = "DynamicButton" & ButtonNumber
        dynamicButton.Font = New Font("Georgia", 10)
        AddHandler dynamicButton.Click, AddressOf dynamicButton_Click
        ' Add Button to the Form. Placement of the Button
        ' will be based on the Location and Size of button
        Controls.Add(dynamicButton)
        axisY = axisY + 35
        ButtonNumber = ButtonNumber + 1
    Loop
    'Add Exit Button
    Dim dynamicButtonExit As New Button
    ' Set Button properties
    dynamicButtonExit.Location = New Point(axisX, axisY)
    dynamicButtonExit.Height = 30
    dynamicButtonExit.Width = 200
    ' Set background and foreground
    dynamicButtonExit.BackColor = Color.Beige
    dynamicButtonExit.ForeColor = Color.Black
    dynamicButtonExit.Text = "Exit"
    dynamicButtonExit.Name = "Exit"
    dynamicButtonExit.Font = New Font("Georgia", 10)
    AddHandler dynamicButtonExit.Click, AddressOf dynamicButtonExit_Click
    ' Add Button to the Form. Placement of the Button
    ' will be based on the Location and Size of button
    Controls.Add(dynamicButtonExit)
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create multiple event to handle your dynamic buttons, dynamicButton_Click is enough to handle all click. Better give ID for each button and you only need to do is in this event, do code as below:

```
Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
If btn.ID = "DynamicButton1" then
    'Do logic here for button 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a little logic to handle each button click in the one event handler. If you use as 'Select Case' Statement it keeps things tidy as well.

If you have a lot of code for each button's logic, it may be better to write separate subs for each button and call the appropriate sub using each 'Case' block like in the second case block

```
Private Sub DynamicButton_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Select Case btn.Name
        Case "DynamicButton1"
            MessageBox.Show("button1")
        Case "DynamicButton2"
            dynamicbutton2_Click(sender, e)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub dynamicbutton2_Click(sender As Button, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Button2")
    'and lots of other code
End Sub
```