# Creating a dynamic button on a dymanic form

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, controls

I am creating a form, text box and button at run time and am having issues trying to add the event handler for the click event of the button (code below).  I think an inline function may be the way to go, but I have not used these a great deal and looking at examples written in C# but not been able to convert this to vb.net, possibly this isn't the way to go though.

As for my reasoning for taking this approach it's just to learn how to do this, I could create a windows form and do it that way but It's always good to try something new. Willing to accept a critique of my code but as ever please make this constructive.

```
        Dim CommandButton As New Button
        With CommandButton
            .Text = "Submit"
            .Name = "btnComments"
            .Location = New Point(232, 110)
            .Font = New Font("Tahoma", 12)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(130, 32)
        End With

        Dim TextBox As New TextBox
        With TextBox
            .Name = "CommentsText"
            .Location = New Point(20, 20)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(342, 80)
            .Multiline = True
            .BackColor = Color.Snow
        End With

        Dim CommentsForm As New Windows.Forms.Form
        With CommentsForm
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
            .Height = 195
            .Width = 400
            .Text = "Enter despatch comments for " & Me.ReferenceValue
            .Controls.Add(TextBox)
            .Controls.Add(CommandButton)
            .MaximizeBox = False
            .MinimizeBox = False
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
            .ShowDialog()
        End With
```

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler

Comment: These appear to be from where the form object already exists unless I am mistaken and if so then is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

To add a handler to a Control dynamically, use `AddHandler yourControlName.eventToHandle, AddressOf handlingMethod`.

Comment: Again you're missing the point.  The form doesn't exist so there is no event that you can reference using AddressOf.  Both the control and the form are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddHandler to add a handler for any event.

For example, this might be:

AddHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.theButton_Click