# Create dynamically a button and add EventHandler()

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, eventhandler, c#-to-vb.net

I am migrating a C# WinForm Application to VB.Net.

In part of the code define a Button and Add a EventHandler to a Method.

```cs
 ToolStripButton newExportButton = new ToolStripButton();
  newExportButton = new ToolStripButton("", null, new EventHandler(ExportReport));

  private void ExportReport(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = Visor.ObtenerFiltroDeExtensiones();

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && Path.HasExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                ReportDocument reportDocument = this.VisorReporte.ReportSource as ReportDocument;               
                reportDocument.ExportToDisk(dicExtensiones[Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName)], saveFileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }
```

When I try to migrate to Vb.Net I have problems to migrate the EventHandler.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler) But it does not fits to what I need. I am not defining any specified event like (click)

I have changed that line to this one

```
  newExportButton = New ToolStripButton("", Nothing, New EventHandler(ExportarReporte))
```

I have an error saying `AddressOf` is missing.

How can I attach an event Handler to that Button to call specific Method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET you must use the [**`AddressOf` operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator) when referring directly to a method. It is used to create a delegate of the method in question.

`New EventHandler(...)` is not necessary as the delegate is implicitly casted to an event handler if its signature is correct.

This should work:

```vb
newExportButton = New ToolStripButton("", Nothing, AddressOf ExportarReporte)
```