# Getting text from dynamically created radio buttons in a Table

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

In a recent VB project, I was asked to create a Quiz template in Windows Forms. The concept is to read from a txt file how many radio buttons and questions the user has to answer. In order to achieve that, I created and stored dynamically each radio button in Table1.Controls, Table1 is my table. When I try to handle the "enter" event, it does not return in the sender text, or even type. It still says that the sender is Table1. How to know what item on that Table triggered the Event? Thanks. Here is the code of creating the radios:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To (bullets_num)
        Dim rdo As New RadioButton
        rdo.Name = "RadioButton" & i
        If ansArr.Length < bullets_num Then
            rdo.Text = i
        Else
            rdo.Text = ansArr(i)
        End If
        rdo.Location = New Point(5, 30 * i)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(rdo)

Next
```

Comment: So your question not really about getting text from controls, but adding event handlers?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: If @Plutonix is correct in that you are really asking how to add handlers, this post should help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler

Comment: ...and rather than creating N sets of controls, you could create one set at design time and simply change the Q&A contents and use Next / Prev buttons.  A bit more efficient, less costly