# How do I ask for multiple Picturebox-Clickevents in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox, mouseclick-event

I have a 10x10 Array of Pictureboxes that the user needs to click and I'm obviously too lazy to write 100 single "Picturebox.Onclick"-Paragraphs, one for each Picturebox in the Array. What can I do?

The only way I know is to have one Paragraph for each Picturebox and I have done this for up to, like, 8 Pictureboxes. But for 100? Naaahhh.
I know there has to be an easier way but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is a Paragraph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Comment: Use a Collection type to organize your PicureBoxes (a `List<PictureBox>`, but you probably want a `List<class>`, a specialized class that keeps track of your objects and adds some *value*, using specific methods an properties), add the same EventHandler(s) to all your Controls, use the `sender` object to discriminate between the different objects that rise the event(s).

Comment: @Jimi this is vb not c#.

Comment: Ah, my bad :) So, read `List(Of PictureBox)` and `List(Of class)`.

Comment: In the designer, select all the `PictureBoxes`. Open the Properties window and click the Events button at the top. Double-click the `Click` event, Voila! You now have a single event handler with every `PictureBox` in the `Handles` clause. Inside the event handler, the `sender` parameter is the `PictureBox` that was clicked. You can use `DirectCast` to cast as type `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your array of picture boxes to a list then add an handler to the mouse click event of the items in the list. Like this

```
 Dim piclist As New List (Of PictureBox)
 'Convert 2d array to 1d array and store in a List
 '***********************
 ' Replace picarr with the name of your picture box array
 For x As Integer = 0 To 9
     For y As Integer = 0 To 9
         piclist.Items.Add(picarr(x,y)
     Next
 Next
 '*************************

 For Each item As PictureBox in piclist
      AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf picclick
 Next

 Public Sub picclick (sender As Object,  e As EventArgs)
     'Add actions here
 End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim piclist As New List (Of PictureBox) = arr.ToList` I don't believe that this will work with a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @Mary I have updated the answer. Thanks for the correction.