# How do I add an on click event to image button added from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am loading all images in a folder on page load by an image button from code behind.

The images are added correctly but I want to hook up an onclick event unto the image button added dynamically.

Below is my code

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        For Each strfilename As String In Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/glypics/"))
            Dim imgbtn As New ImageButton
            Dim fileinfo As New FileInfo(strfilename)


            imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/glypics/" + fileinfo.Name
            imgbtn.Width = Unit.Pixel(250)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(imgbtn)
            imgbtn.Style.Add("padding", "3px")
  Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what an imagebutton is? But assuming it's anything like a button you just have to add a handler, which can be done a number of ways.

```
    Dim imgbtn As New Button
    AddHandler imgbtn.Click, Sub()
                                 'do stuff
                             End Sub
```

Or

```
    Dim imgbtn As New Button
    AddHandler imgbtn.Click, AddressOf DoClick


Private Sub DoClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Do Stuff
End Sub
```

The latter is more easily removed if needed

```
RemoveHandler imgbtn.Click, AddressOf DoClick
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Addhandler imgbtn.MouseClick, AddressOf imgbtn_MouseClick` in your function then create the called function.

```
Sub imgbtn_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    'Image Button clicked...
End Sub
```