# How to assign code to a code created button?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing something in vb 2010, what I did was a Form which has a button "new", this shows a new form which is created by code on execution time and this form contains a textbox and two more buttons. the problem is, how can I add code for the buttons b1 or b2 created? how can I store the data from the textbox in a variable when I do click on one button or something else. I've read some post asking somthing similar here but they're all related to VBA. I wrote the whole code below. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim f As New Form  
Dim TB As New TextBox
    Dim b1, b2 As New Button
    Dim l As New Label
    With f
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(220, 120)
        .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        .Text = "new"
        .MinimizeBox = False
        .MaximizeBox = False
        .Controls.Add(b1)
        .Controls.Add(b2)
        .Controls.Add(TB)
        .Controls.Add(l)
    End With
    With l
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
        .Location = New Point(10, 3)
        .Text = "label"
    End With
    With TB
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(180, 30)
        .Location = New Point(10, 20)
        .Text = ""
    End With
    With b1
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 30)
        .Location = New Point(30, 50)
        .Text = "create"
    End With
    With b2
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 30)
        .Location = New Point(120, 50)
        .Text = "cancel"
    End With
    f.Show()
```

End Sub

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net

Comment: Yes I've tried it showing an msgbox to confirm that works properly, but it shows the msgbox as the same time as the created form does

Comment: Not a dupe - AddHandler requires the address of existing event handler.  You'd be better off using an "empty" form with some code in it and just add controls to it and map them to existing handlers.  If thats not doable, you may have to resort to CodeDOM

Comment: The duplicate is the way to do it. If that is not working, something else is wrong. Regarding the Textbox question, you just need to either hold reference to the textbox as a global variable so you can access it from the handler, or use the handler's sender object to get the parent (Which is the form) and find the textbox through it.

Answer (score 0):

For your displaying the textbox text problem, you can use a lambda expression for the handler which keeps all of the variables in scope and allows you to access the textbox directly.

```
... code above from your example ...
With b2
    .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 30)
    .Location = New Point(120, 50)
    .Text = "cancel"
End With

AddHandler b1.Click, Sub(s, e2)
                         MsgBox(TB.Text)
                     End Sub

f.Show()
```

Comment: If this solved your problem mark it as the answer :)