# How do I create an event handler for a programmatically created PictureBox Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, event-handling

I have created a two-dimensional array of PictureBoxes, and I want to add a DragDrop event to all the elements of the array.

```
 For x As Integer = 1 To 16
        For y As Integer = 1 To 4
            p(x, y) = New PictureBox()
            p(x, y).Image = My.Resources.Kästchen
            p(x, y).Location = New Point(pMain.Left + x * 48, pMain.Top + y * 48)
            p(x, y).Size = New Size(48, 48)
            p(x, y).Name =  "p"+str(x)+str(y)
            AddHandler p(x, y).DragDrop, AddressOf p(x,y)_DragDrop

            p(x, y).Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(p(x, y))

            
        Next
    Next
```

I know that there's a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net), but I wasn't able to adapt it to arrays.
How do I add the  DragDrop Event for all the PictureBoxes, which are created during runtime?

Comment: Since the number of controls is hardcoded, why not put them on the form in the designer?  You can still store a reference to them in an array for looping.  Note that your app is likely leaking and array indices start at 0.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a sub named `p(x,y)_DragDrop`. You need to create a sub with the signature `(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)`, and use `sender` to identify the picturebox.

Comment: So I have to create a Sub for each picture box?

Comment: I came up with this, but it shows the error: "." expected
    Private Sub p11(p11 As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles p(1,1).DragDrop

    End Sub

Comment: @Cyrill : No, just create one event handler for all picture boxes: `Private Sub PictureBoxes_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)` (notice that there's no `Handles ...` on the end), then: `AddHandler p(x, y).DragDrop, AddressOf PictureBoxes_DragDrop`.