# System.Object and System.EventArgs

Tags: ms-access, events, vba, addhandler

I'm trying to write a simple calendar for selecting dates. I have an array of PushButtons, and now I'm trying to programmatically add event handlers.

```
Public Sub Initialize()

    If EventID = 0 Then
        GetEmployeeData
        EventType = "Attendance"
    Else
        GetEventData
    End If

    Dim Days
    Days = Array(Sunday0, Monday0, Tuesday0, Wednesday0, Thursday0, Friday0, Saturday0, _
    Sunday1, Monday1, Tuesday1, Wednesday1, Thursday1, Friday1, Saturday1, _
    Sunday2, Monday2, Tuesday2, Wednesday2, Thursday2, Friday2, Saturday2, _
    Sunday3, Monday3, Tuesday3, Wednesday3, Thursday3, Friday3, Saturday3, _
    Sunday4, Monday4, Tuesday4, Wednesday4, Thursday4, Friday4, Saturday4, _
    Sunday5, Monday5, Tuesday5, Wednesday5, Thursday5, Friday5, Saturday5)

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To 41
        AddHandler Days(j).Click, AddressOf Calendar_Click
    Next j
End Sub

Public Sub Calendar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim CalendarDay As Integer
    CalendarDay = Convert.Int32(sender.Caption)
    MsgBox (CalendarDay)
End Sub
```

However, when I try to run the form, I get an error message reading

> Compile Error: User-defined type not defined.

**Update**

I changed the event handler signature to this:

```
Public Sub Calendar_Click(ByVal sender As Object)
```

but now I get the following error:

> Compile Error: Invalid use of AddressOf operator

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET?  If it's VBA, you need to use the VBA event signature.

Comment: How do I find out? I'm using Visual Basic for Access, not too clear on the difference.

Comment: Ah, it says right there at the top: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications.

Comment: On the top of what? Because that isn't VBA code.

Comment: That's what the window says. I'm using Access 2016.

Comment: Where did the code come from?

Comment: The EventHandler code is from SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net

Comment: That's a VB.NET question. [Take a look at this one instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: That one doesn't seem to address how to dynamically add an event handler. Is this possible in Visual Basic for Access?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use dynamic event handlers in Access. But every object needs to have it's own event handler.

You can use a separate class for each button, and a class to manage the buttons and the events.

You can use the following code:

**clsCalendar** (the class that creates event handlers, and receives the events back)

```
Dim collButtonHandlers As Collection
Public Sub Initialize()
    Dim Days
    Days = Array(Sunday0, Monday0, Tuesday0, Wednesday0, Thursday0, Friday0, Saturday0, _
    Sunday1, Monday1, Tuesday1, Wednesday1, Thursday1, Friday1, Saturday1, _
    Sunday2, Monday2, Tuesday2, Wednesday2, Thursday2, Friday2, Saturday2, _
    Sunday3, Monday3, Tuesday3, Wednesday3, Thursday3, Friday3, Saturday3, _
    Sunday4, Monday4, Tuesday4, Wednesday4, Thursday4, Friday4, Saturday4, _
    Sunday5, Monday5, Tuesday5, Wednesday5, Thursday5, Friday5, Saturday5)
    'I assume that array is now filled with command buttons
    'Consider taking the array as input from a form
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To 41
        AddButtonHandler Days(j)
    Next j
End Sub

Public Sub AddButtonHandler(btn As Access.CommandButton)
    Dim ButtonHandler As New clsCalendarButtonHandler
    ButtonHandler.Initialize btn, Me
    collButtonHandlers.Add ButtonHandler
End Sub

Public Sub Calendar_Click(btn As Access.CommandButton)
    Dim CalendarDay As Integer
    CalendarDay = CLng(btn.Caption)
    MsgBox (CalendarDay)
End Sub
```

**clsCalendarButtonHandler** (the class that manages a single button event, and passes it back to the managing class):

```
Dim cCalendar As clsCalendar
Dim btn As Access.CommandButton
Public Sub Initialize(cmdBtn As Access.CommandButton, Calendar As clsCalendar)
    Set cCalendar = Calendar
    Set btn = cmdBtn
    btn.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Click()
    cCalendar.Calendar_Click(btn)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This isnt possible in Access 2016. Handlers exist in VB.Net but not in Access VBA. I can only think of something like that. But if its makes sense is another question:

```
Public Sub MyEventSelection(Day As String)

  Select Case Day

    Case "Sunday0"
      Call Sunday0()
    Case "Monday0"
      Call Monday0()

    'And so on...

  End Select

End Sub

Public Sub Sunday0()
  'Do Stuff
End Sub

Public Sub Monday0()
  'Do Stuff
End Sub
```

Maybe you should rethink your needed code.

Comment: Event handlers certainly do exist in VBA. See the [comment by ComIntern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886276/system-object-and-system-eventargs#comment90724311_51886276), for example.

Comment: Sorry my expression is misleading. With event handlers I meant the VB.Net `Private Sub Test() Handles ...` and the `Address Of ...` Code