# How do I make controls inside of a FlowLayoutPanel do things?

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding controls to a `FlowLayoutPanel` like this:

```vb
Dim box As New PictureBox
```

(I'm making the controls using code, then I'm using `FlowPanelLayout1.Controls.Add(box)`).

How do I make these controls do things? In my code I'm using `For Each`, so multiple are made using this, my goal is to make each one be able to do what I want and the code for each would be different. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "do things"? Please post the code of your `For Each` loop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant I want to be able to add code to the controls. Example: The first one generated makes a Msgbox with something in it but the second one added makes a msgbox with a different value.

Comment: If you have added an event handler, the `sender` object is the Control that generated the event. Cast `sender` to Control (or to a specific control type, PictureBox here) so you can directly *commandeer* the Control.

Comment: Update: I meant for them to be added on click. I don't know if that works the same but if it does, I'll look into that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net

Comment: *"I meant I want to be able to add code to the controls"*. No you didn't. You can't add any code to the controls. Microsoft wrote the code for those controls and you can't change that. What you can do is add code to your form to handle the events that those controls raise. That's what you meant. Your question is how to handle events of objects (that they are controls isn't relevant in this context) created at run time. That question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're after is AddHandler. AddHandler allows you to programmatically assign code to an event at runtime. So you can create a Sub specifically to handle events from the picture boxes you create.

You can also retrieve the control that raised the event. This allows you to modify it, or access it's tag, allowing you to attach data to the PictureBox when you add it to the FlowLayoutPanel.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create a new picturebox
    Dim PB As New PictureBox With {.Size = New Drawing.Size(50, 50), .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal}
    PB.Image = Image.FromFile("res.png")
    'Add it to the FlowLayoutPanel
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(PB)
    'Assign HandlePictureboxClick() to handle the PictureBox's DoubleClick event.
    AddHandler PB.DoubleClick, AddressOf HandlePictureboxClick
End Sub

Public Sub HandlePictureboxClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Retrive the control that raised the event (In this case, the one you double-clicked)
    Dim Picturebox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    'Do whatever you want to do with it
    Picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
End Sub
```

The example above will change the PictureBox's size mode to zoom when the user double clicks on it, without modifying the other PictureBoxes in the FlowLayoutPanel