# Add event handlers for runtime created controls in runtime created forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

Im making a class that will show a form with some text and a OK button. But I can't seem to find how to handle clicking the OK button. Here is the code that im having problems with:

```
Private Sub ok_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myForm.okButton.Click
    'code
End Sub
```

Runtime form is called `myForm`

Runtime button is called `okButton`

How I can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic button click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Comment: @Codexer I don't think so because my form is dynamically created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an event handler for a programmatically created object in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement):

```
' ... run-time control is created ...
Dim btn As New Button
btn.Text = "Hello World!"
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ok_click
```

In your existing handler, you do NOT use the "Handles" keyword on the end.  If you need a reference to the button, use the "sender" parameter:

```
Private Sub ok_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    ' ... do something with "btn" ...
    btn.Enabled = False
End Sub
```